# Regex value match for 0.000001

Tags: regex

I am using `[0]{0,8}.[0]{5}[1]` regex for `0.000001` value check (0-8 positions zero's and exactly 5 zeros to the right and 1) but it is accepting `000000000.000001` as well, can you suggest a regular expression which can validate `"0.000001"`?

Comment: Use word boundaries?

Comment: `0\.000001` is a valid regex for the test cases you have provided. If that doesn't match your needs, please be more specific :)

Comment: @Shadow thanks 0\.000001 matches the value and can you tell me the regex for "00000000.000001"

Comment: @Shadow The OP also provided `000000000.000001` as a test case that should fail. `/0\.000001/` would still match that.

Comment: @Nizampatnam well... `00000000\.000001` would...

Comment: @Xufox - depends on which regex engine you're using (ie whether it looks for a full match or not). But true, `^0\.000001$` would be more specific.

Comment: I need exactly 8 digits to the left and when I am testing for 0.000001 input value like 00.000001 should also be not accepted right?

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to match a word boundary at the beginning and end, so it won't match this number as part of a longer number. `\b` matches a word boundary. Or if this is supposed to match the entire input string, use `^` and `$` anchors.

Second, you need to escape `.` in the regexp, so it will match the `.` character literally, not match any character.

There's no need to put `0` inside `[]`. That's only needed if you want to match any of multiple characters.

```
\b0{0,8}\.0{5}1\b
```